# Red Hat Satellite vs. Ubuntu Landscape

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat

We have some experience using Red Hat Satellite in an environment with ~120 servers. Now we're looking into deploying Ubuntu in parallel for the further growth.

How does Landscape compare to Satellite with regards to features and usability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satellite went open source, called [Spacewalk](http://www.redhat.com/spacewalk/), i would kill for an opensourced Landscape...

Anyway, there's a project for [supporting deb files on spacewalk](https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/wiki/Deb_support_in_spacewalk), but I don't know what status does it have...

Comment: Landscape does have an off-line install feature: 

http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/landscape/hosting-options

Comment: Finally! :D
It didn't at the time of the question :P

Comment: Landscape on-site installation is called "Landscape Dedicated Server" apparently https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/Installation :)

Comment: Now called, OPL, On Premises Landscape :) ;)
https://help.landscape.canonical.com/

Answer (score -1):

For Debian based operating systems, you can use apt-dater
https://mpdeveloper.blogspot.com/2022/01/apt-dater-los-parches-de-seguridad-es.html

Comment: How does apt-dater relate to landscape and satellite? A Spanish Blogpost is not helpful to the majority of the English speaking audience of this site.